# Jquery does not work with Prototype

Tags: jquery, ajax, prototypejs, conflict

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
    var $jq = jQuery.noConflict();
    $jq(document).ready(function(){
        alert("123");
        $jq("#redactor_content").redactor();
        alert("456");
    });
</script>
<script src="prototype.js"></script>
<script src="redactor.js"></script>
```

"redactor.js" is the WYSIWYG-editor based on JQuery: http://imperavi.com/download/redactor/get/ with that source:

```
...
(function($){
   // Initialization
   $.fn.redactor = function(options)
   { ... };
})(jQuery);
...
```

When I comment "prototype.js" - everything works(I see "123456").

With  "prototype.js" - see only "123" and "redactor" doesn't work. (It's means that the namespace is working correctly, right? Why then the second alert is not working?)

When I comment only `$jq(document).ready(function(){` and move "redactor.js" before calling (call "`redactor()`" without waiting DOM) - everything fine too.

I do not understand the principle. After including "jquery.js" I first "$" overwrite and then include  "prototype.js" to avoid conflicts. But Namespace Jquery somehow still intersects with Prototype. I suspect that the error is somewhere here: `$jq("#redactor_content").redactor();` and I need to do something like: `.redactor($jq);`, but it broke my head and I can not guess.

**P.S.:** Yeah, I read the documentation ( http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries ) and tried different ways(swaps  libraries and try `$.noConflict`, `jQuery(document).ready...)`. I wrote an example that anything is working and there is some clarity.

My second question: will it work together: `jQuery(document).ready(function()` and Prototype's `document.observe("dom:loaded", function()` and if NO, how to get to work together?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried this structure for your code(not redactor) (function($){ // Code... })(jQuery);

Comment: Yes, I tried to do something like:  <script>
    (function($){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        alert("123");
        $("#redactor_content").redactor();
        alert("456");
    }); })(jQuery);
</script> But I do not remember what was the result. Just do not work.

Comment: When you use "(function($){...})(jQuery);", you don't need "$(document).ready(". Also remember that you have to load redactor.js before you use it. So correct order is: jQuery, redactor, prototype, yout script.

Comment: But this "$(document).ready(" is to be executed after the DOM loading. If I remove it, then there will be a different meaning.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing

```
<script>
    var $jq = jQuery.noConflict();
    $jq(document).ready(function(){
        alert("123");
        $jq("#redactor_content").redactor();
        alert("456");
    });
</script>
```

with

```
<script>
(function($){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        alert("123");
        $("#redactor_content").redactor();
        alert("456");
    });
})(jQuery);  
</script>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I see only "123" :(  <script src="/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
 <script>
  (function($){
      $(document).ready(function(){
          alert("123");
          $("#redactor_content").redactor();
          alert("456");
      });
  })(jQuery);  
 </script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="/prototype.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/redactor.js"></script>

Comment: Without "$(document).ready(function(){" - it works, but I need the code execute when the DOM is fully loaded

Comment: @Vladislav You must include jQuery, redactor.js, the custom script, then prototype in this order.

Comment: <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/redactor.js"></script>
 <script>
  (function($){
      $(document).ready(function(){
          alert("123");
          $("#redactor_content").redactor();
          alert("456");
      });
  })(jQuery);  
 </script> 

 <script type="text/javascript" src="/prototype.js" charset="utf-8"></script> There is no difference. I see only "123."

Comment: The same without "$(document).ready(function(){" - works (see "123456"). So, this means that the code is executed only if prototype.js is not yet loaded.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see, this should work. The only thing that could go wrong is that redactor.js needs the $-assignment somewhere in its code (which would be a bug there), but it seems to handle that correctly.

You could test that by loading prototype first, then jquery + redactor.js, then using jQuery.noConflict() (that switches back the $-operator to the previous value, prototype in this example).

Btw, I would expect some error in the console if the second alert doesn't pop up, that would be relevant info too.

And to your second question: Yes, both methods should work fine. But you only need 1 of course :).

Comment: Yeah, console: "TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'this.opts.css[key].substr(0,1)')" Here(redactor.js): for (key in this.opts.css)
            {
                if (this.opts.css[key].substr(0,1) != '/') this.cssUrl[key] = this.opts.pathCss + this.opts.css[key];
                else this.cssUrl[key] = this.opts.css[key];
            }

Comment: Thanks! What I can do with that? Why I need only 1 method?

Comment: You only need 1 because both of them do the same thing, it's not as if you can only use jQuery in one, and only prototype in the other.

And if the problem is in the redactor.js, it will be hard to debug. Maybe you should mark it as a bug for redactor.js.